# How to find documents that contain certain value in any of sub-object's key-value mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find if some document exists that match 2 filters :

1. licenseType = "Trial"
2. machineId object contains at least one value that match "ABC"

Normally, in javascript, I would have done something like:

```
Object.values(machineId).includes("ABC")
```

But I need to put something similar in the filter option of mongoose's `findOne()` or `exists()`.

My document looks like this:

```
{
  licenseType : "Trial",
  machineId : {
    0: null,
    1: "ABC",
    2: "null",
    ...
  },
}
```

`machineId` is an object that contains a variable number of values.

My query looks like this for now :

```
const licenses = await License.exists({
      machineId: { $in: ["ABC"] },
      licenseType: "Trial",
    })
```

But it doesn't work.

**How to find if any of `machineId` value is equal to `"ABC"` ?**
Are there different methods if it's done with javascript or in MongoDB prompt ? I would like to be able to reproduce this query outsite of my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const licenseExists = await License.exists({
  licenseType: "Trial",
  machineId: { $regex: /ABC/i }
});
```

I am using regex which is case in-sensitive here , this will return `boolean` , if you want the object to return, you could use `findOne` in place of `exists`. Let me know if this is the one you looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried it, it does work with an array, but not with an object.

Comment: try this , it will return all documents which has 'macheineId' fields that contains ABC : 

const license = await License.find({ licenseType: "Trial", machineId: { $in: ["ABC"] } });

Comment: Already tried it too, same result, works with arrays but not with objects...